# Does WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER grant cross-database permissions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, impersonation, cross-database

Suppose that I have `[DataBase1].[dbo].[MyStoredProc]`. It modifies `[DataBase1].[dbo].[HarmlessTable]` and `[DataBase2].[dbo].[DangerousTable]`. Notice that these are not in the same database. Consider a user with all of the relevant permissions in `[DataBase1]` but no permissions at all in `[DataBase2]`.

If I put `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` in `[DataBase1].[dbo].[MyStoredProc]`, will they be able to run that stored procedure and edit `[DataBase2].[dbo].[DangerousTable]`?

Comment: Silly question: did you try it? Are your databases marked as trustworthy and have ownership chaining enabled?

Comment: @AaronBertrand No. I don't meddle with permissions lightly.

Comment: You don't have local/dev/test/staging environments?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not giving users permissions in my test environment and then going through the trouble of getting them to try to connect and run a script again it.

Comment: If I was concerned about the permissions like this I would much rather try it out myself instead of taking the word of "some dude on the internet said...".

Comment: Does owner of procedure has access to database2? if yes, then yes

Comment: Wow, that is not what I expected at all. Ok, have fun with your problem.

Comment: *" I'm not giving users permissions in my test environment and then going through the trouble of getting them to try to connect and run a script again it."* Why would you get *them* to do it? As the DBA you can create a *test* account impersonate them and test all you want...

Comment: You can do all of this testing with localdb. And just create throwaway temporary users that you yourself can log in as or impersonate (SQL authenticated or without login)

Comment: @ThomA I've had little success with impersonation in the past. I suppose I can try it again.

Comment: @siggemannen it's actually not as simple as that. By default ownership chains end at the database level.

Comment: You are much better off not using chaining at all, and instead use code signing with a certificate, and giving *that* certificate permissions on the other database. See eg https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/cross-db-access-with-module-signing/

Comment: @Charlieface I had that in mind, but my history with certificates is an awful one. They create more problems for me than they solve.

Comment: With respect, it sounds like the *real* problem here is your ability to use the tools to check how things work or implement them; perhaps you should be asking questions about that.

Comment: @ThomA I think I'm close to understanding it all. I just have a lot of bad experiences in this specific area so I'm distrustful of *everything*, including what ought to be sensible tests.

Comment: So instead you want to use a much more risky setup which might allow your server and databases to be hacked? There are plenty tutorials out there showing this exact thing

Comment: @Charlieface To my knowledge, `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` Is fine as long as I don't allow any SQL injection in the relevant procedure.

Comment: Well you also need to make your database `TRUSTWORTHY` and allow cross-DB chaining, which means anyone with `ALTER PROC` access on it might be able to create or change the procedure to do something else. Certificates are not that difficult, and are the recommended way to do this.

Comment: @Charlieface I have no desire to make my database `TRUSTWORTHY`. If that is a required step for making `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` do what I want, then that's all that I need to know.

Comment: @ThomA Where should I go to learn more about this? I've read SQL books (Itzik Ben-Gan is my go to), but permissions management has never been in them. I read the documentation for `WITH EXECUTE` but I didn't see anything about cross-database stuff.

Comment: @Charlieface you don't need `TRUSTWORTHY` for cross database chaining.

Comment: @ThomA Explicitly turning on cross-database permission chaining isn't something I would like to do either.

Comment: Sounds liek Certificates is what you want then, @J.Mini .

Comment: @ThomA It's sounding that way. It's certainly my next choice after what I asked about.

Comment: @J.Mini, TL;DR see [Erland's article](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) on certificates. I use one cert per proc and use a utility proc to (re)create the cert, cert user, grant permissions, and copy the cert to other databases whenever the proc is deployed.

Comment: @DanGuzman - I created a similar setup once upon a time using a DDL trigger and a table to drive what objects should be signed by what certificates. I even had the presence of mind to put it on [github](https://github.com/ben-thul/auto-pen). Might be useful to OP

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> OWNER
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module executes in the context of the current owner of the module.

in this case, the owner of the module would be whichever **user** created `[DataBase1].[dbo].[MyStoredProc]`. Users don't have permissions outside of the database where they reside. Their logins may do, but that's not relevant ([example here](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#execasserver)).

Given that you are only copying the user's permissions and the user doesn't have permissions outside of the database in question, `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` will not grant cross-database permissions.